# KDTree Distorting Buffer Geometry

Tags: three.js

I have a BufferGeometry which has many faces that are colored. When I try applying a KDTree to the positions of the BufferGeometry with

`new THREE.TypedArrayUtils.Kdtree(bufferGeometry.attributes.position.array, distanceFunction, 3);`

I get my geometry distorted to this:[image]

When it's supposed to be like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`THREE.TypedArrayUtils.Kdtree` sorts the supplied array in-place. You could copy your array and see if it works then.

```
new THREE.TypedArrayUtils.Kdtree(bufferGeometry.attributes.position.array.slice(0), distanceFunction, 3);
```

Note the `.slice(0);`

Comment: I have tried this before posting here thinking it did this, however, it did not work. I also tried initializing a separate variable for it and working off that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `subarray(0)`, I found that you had to initialize a new Float32Array and then set that variable to the array of your other variable.

```
var newArray = new Float32Array(bufferGeometry.attributes.position.array.length);
newArray.set(bufferGeometry.attributes.position.array);
```

Comment: Yeah the kdtree is designed for high preformance. Therefore it works on the positions you provide it, doing every single thing inplace. If you don't want that (and you don't since it sorta destroys your geometry ^^) you can just copy it beforehand.

Comment: subarray does not create a new array, it only creates an array-view with the specific bounds